# 404 messages when starting CM explorer

Tags: core-service, cme, configuration

We are running 2011 SP1 - HR1. Recently we started getting the following sequence of messages in the message centre when starting the GUI

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
Loading list of languages failed
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
Loading list of locales failed
```

The browser itself is not getting a 404 status on any response, so this looks to me like failed requests against the core service running server-side. However, I haven't been able to find any matching evidence in the logs on the server.

What further steps can I take to diagnose the root cause? Is there more logging available that I can enable? Are there any likely causes that I should be aware of?

What might be the cause of this happening on a previously well-behaved system? (I'm thinking Windows update.... anyone else seen a recent bad patch? What else might it be?)

**Update:** we are seeing 401 statuses for URLs such as `/WebUI/Core/Controls/Tree/TreeHead.xml`. Might this be related?

**Update:** Once the GUI has loaded, you can navigate around, and normal item lists will populate as normal, but if you try to load a list of users, you get the 404 again. The user preferences box loads Ok, but the language/locale lists are empty - I guess the GUI only tries to load them once. Can this be something specific to system lists?

Comment: Can you list what addons you have, as it very well might be one of the addons, like Outbound Email?

Comment: It's completely vanilla. We have the razor mediator installed, but I doubt if that's relevant. Other than that, nothing.

Comment: The GUI uses the Core Service via the Tridion Service Host Windows Service.  I would make sure this is started, and also look at the log folder within Tridion to see any error messages from the core service.

Comment: How is authorization set up? Do you see this across browsers?

Comment: We're using Windows authentication, and logging in to Tridion as admins. The issue is the same in IE/FF/Chrome... which doesn't surprise me, because I really think it's on the server.

Comment: 401's are normal behavior in most cases I thought, you first get a 401 and then the request is automatically retried with credentials, that's how I understood a browser normally works.

Comment: good point Bart.

Comment: Have you set it up on a custom host header? Has this been configured correctly?

Comment: Thanks Ryan - that turned out to be it. I'd removed a binding in IIS and still had the old binding in the Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo configuration. If you post an answer about custom host headers, I'll add some details. Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set up a new instance of SDL Tridion and you would like it to run under a custom binding you need to ensure that the configuration files are set up correctly to handle it.

The configuration files are mentioned in this question on setting up SDL Tridion with multiple hosts headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428360/i-set-up-my-sdl-tridion-2011-instance-to-run-with-multiple-host-headers-and-now/

Comment: That was the problem. The Tridion explorer web site originally had two bindings (a named one, and a default localhost:80 one). Both of these were correctly configured in the CME web.config as Tridion.WPF.RedirectTo and baseAddressPrefixFilters. Then I assigned the default localhost:80 binding to a different web site, and failed to update these settings. The result was that Tridion was attempting to make calls to endpoints on localhost:80 that didn't exist. Thanks.

Comment: Oh dear. I knew this was familiar. I've just come across a "note to self" I wrote back in December http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/mysterious-404-errors-showing-up-in-the-tridion-message-centre Oh well - can't win em all.